# Checking a string input equality inside a .jsp , only in the client side ?

Tags: java, html, jsp, el

The user has a label to fill in and I want to check if:

`'his_input' == 'some text'.`

I have sent the `'sometext'` value inside the client page, so I wish to avoid to send it back to the server and do the test on the client side ?

*I am trying to learn jsp, EL currently*

Comment: you need to use javascript for client side checking

Comment: OK, thanks. Well I planned to learn javascript too anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    //YOU CAN PUT CHECK IN FUNCTION WHICH WILL BE CALLED ON EVENT (`click`,`keyup`)
    var val = document.getElementById('txt_id').value;
    if(val == 'Some text'){
        // your code goes here
    }else{
        // your code goes here
    }
```

**HTML**

```
    <input type="text" name="mytext" id="txt_id"/>
```

Comment: thanks ! I never did any JavaScript so I will need some time even for something that simple.